# Prove By Induction (Fibonacci Sequence)

Tags: induction

Prove by PMI $\gcd(f_n,f_{n+1}) = 1$ for all natural numbers $n$. $f_n$ represents the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: What are your own thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Three consecutive terms in a Fibonacci sequence can be written as $a,b,a+b$. If $d$ divides $b$ and $d$ divides $a+b$, then $d$ divides $a+b-b=a$.

Comment: Congratulations on $2000$, but don't leave us friend :).

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:*  $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a-b,b)$.

Comment: How can you prove this.

Comment: @Ron.J.Adams By applying any of the definitions of $\gcd$ or one step of the Euclidean algorithm

Comment: Can you show me how?